# How to convert table into a specific XML format using Python?

Tags: python, xml, database

How to convert a table from a database into a specific XML format request by client.I know this can be done in excel using XML mapping.But is there a way I can do using Python?

Comment: There probably is, but this question is a bit too broad to be answered effectively here. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm voting to close this for reasons which should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the python standard library xml: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree

Hope that helps, happy pythoning